# unable to run netca, dbca, and/or netmgr

Tags: dbca

I have the problem when run netca, dbca, netmgr. They worked before and now all are not found when run netca, dbca, or netmgr

```
$ netca &
[1] 116909
$ bash: netca: command not found...
^C
[1]+  Exit 127                netca
```

I do have env on the profile

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhome_1
export LISTENER_NAME=LISTENER
export ORA_INVENTORY=/opt/app/oraInventory
export ORACLE_SID=myhr
#export DATA_DIR=/data/oradata
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib
export DISPLAY="localhost:10.0"
export LC_ALL=C

export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch
```

If I su oracle (without "-"_), the xclock opened but still can't run dbca/netca/netmgr

```
# su oracle
[oracle@nediacredhat8 root]$ xclock
Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion
$dbca &
    [1] 121642
    [oracle@nediacredhat8 root]$ Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
            at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
            at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
            at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.isLowResolution(LookUtils.java:484)
            at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.<clinit>(LookUtils.java:249)
            at com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel.<clinit>(PlasticLookAndFeel.java:136)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
            at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.loadSystemClass(SwingUtilities.java:1879)
            at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:582)
            at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:976)
            at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:181)
            at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:198)
            at oracle.assistants.common.base.driver.AssistantApplication.startup(AssistantApplication.java:340)
            at oracle.assistants.dbca.driver.DBConfigurator.startup(DBConfigurator.java:421)
            at oracle.assistants.dbca.driver.DBConfigurator.main(DBConfigurator.java:556)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable. [in thread "main"]

$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0 
$ echo $PATH
/home/oracle/.local/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhome_1/bin:/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhome_1/OPatch
$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhome_1
```

how do I correct and make it work?